# Order by a field which isn't included on a matrix POWERBI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I'm trying to build a matrix on PowerBI and I want to order the data by a field which I don't want to include in the matrix. My field named "category" in the matrix must be on a especific order, and I create a numeric field to specify the order. But when I want to order by that numeric field, I can't, PowerBI only allows me to order by the field which is in the matrix.
To test it, I concatenated my numeric field with the category like this: `numeric - category`, and it works, but I don't want to show it like that, I want only the category field order by the numeric field.
Any suggestion? Thanks.

EDIT:
I have also tried with "Sort by column", but neither selecting the matrix nor the data source table, the button is not activated.
Also detail that "category" has 2 or more numbers in "order" column.

[image]

Comment: Use "sort by column" feature: https://radacad.com/sort-by-column-in-power-bi

Comment: It doesn't work for me.

Comment: Sort by Column is what you need but I don't know why it's not active. Can you share a PBIX?

Comment: Sorry, data contained is confidential, I can't share it.

Comment: Do not include your data, make a simple pbix to show your use case with mockup data and share it.

Comment: "Sort by column" is the way to do this, but we can't help you figure out why it isn't activated without being able to reproduce the problem. You don't need to share confidential data; just share anything that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Sort by column" was not activated because there were many duplicated rows in "Category" field, so I couldn't sort by "Order" because 2 or more rows share the same "category" with different "Orders". I fixed my database and now I can use the tool.